# Centering Text on a Button with Offset

Tags: button, text, javafx-2

I have a variety of ToggleButtons that are loaded with an image. The buttons size is determinated by the image size and the button itself is created by JavaCode. A few buttons have icons (the icon is just part of the loaded image) on either the left or right side.

How can I move the text by a certain value to the left or right so I can center the text again but with the offset of the icon? I don't mind passing the width of the icon as parameter, but I cant find anything to move the text for a certain amount.

[image]

The button is created from the green image, the right icon is part of it; total width is 300, icon is taking 100; the text should be centered to the leftover 200. For language setting reason the text itself cant be part of the picture.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the style of the button as followed:

```
// top right bottom left
btn.setStyle("-fx-padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;");
```

**EDIT:**
You can use an HBox:

```
HBox hbox = new HBox();
// the text of the "button"
Label lbl_txt = new Label("Text");
// the icon of the "button", i am using Labels for icon(with css)
Label lbl_ico = new Label("ico");
hbox.getChildren().addAll(lbl_txt, lbl_ico);
hbox.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
        // alternative to Button click
    }
});
```

Everything else is styling with css. ;-)

Comment: This wont work, its offsetting the whole button and not just the text for it (not offsetting only the position, but also click able area)

Comment: ok, this was not clear for me from you question.
could you please provide any kind of example or screenshot?

Comment: Well, this could work as a last last last workaround, but I'm more against it, since
- forced to use 3 components instead of one for something simple as placing text
- also I would have to implement the normal button behavior for click events (like pressed state for toggle buttons)

Comment: i am now using javafx for a complex application and I say to you there is no simpler way to do it.
pressed state, hover etc., you can copy from button css..