# Setting state for all children the same as parent

Tags: css, javafx-2

After trying to find a solution for [Centering Text on a Button with Offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16143686/centering-text-on-a-button-with-offset), I'm doing now a custom component.
The goal is to make a button-like component that has an icon on one side and a centered text filling the rest of the button.

The component contains either two Label/ Buttons to display the Icon and text. Both of them have a background Image, defined in css.

The css looks like this for Icon and the text with exchanged image as background for text

```
#button-icon-cancel{
   -fx-font-family: "Arial";  
   -fx-padding: 0,0,0,0; 
   -fx-background-color: transparent; 
   -fx-font-size: 28px;
   -fx-graphic: url('images/button/cancel.png'); 
}

#button-icon-cancel:pressed{  
   -fx-graphic: url('images/button/cancel-pressed.png'); 
}
```

The images are loaded by setId(). Currently both components are added to a Panel before passing to the stage. They contain an OnClickEvent for processing.

**Now to the actual question**

How can I achieve that if one Component is clicked, the other one is getting the :pressed from css as  well?

- Adding the ClickEvent to the Panel is doing nothing (regarding clicking on either Label/ Button)
- Adding both of them to a HBox, adding the Event to the HBox work in that regard, that I can click either component and the Event gets fired, BUT the :pressed State is only applied to the component you clicked.

Is it possible to give all childs the notification, that they should behave like they got pressed? Since we have a lot of small Icon, but only one background for the text, placing a Label over the whole thing create a lot of unneeded wasted Image space. Also this would cause the problematic for changing font color if not all css are changed at once (the label-over-button-solution with `.setMouseTransparent(true)` wouldn't change the font color of the text label since the label doesn't notice button is pressed)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, JFX-8 will support wider range of css improvements, which will allow you to solve the issue easier.

To solve your issue, i can suggest the following : each node have a pressed property. You can add a listener on this property, and when it changes to true, use setStyle(String) method on needed nodes, and use setStyle(null | "") on changing to false.